Prove the convergence of the sample PACF
I'm looking for a proof that the sample PACF converges in probability to the PACF in probability as T goes to infinity when m = p.
Moreover, I am looking for a proof that when m > p, that the sample PACF converges in probability to zero. Furthermore, the sample PACF scaled by sqrt(T) converges in distribution to N(0,1).
I couldn't find one in my standard time series textbook. Cheers!
